# Wordpress keeps switching back to empty template

Tags: themes, templates

I've created a custom page template with a hero and a subnavigation section that fetches some data from custom fields and shows a menu. Here's the code:

```
<?php
/**
 * Template Name: Hero Page Template 
 *
 * Template for displaying a page with Hero and sub navigation component.
 *
 * @package understrap
 */

// Exit if accessed directly.
defined( 'ABSPATH' ) || exit;

get_header();
$container = get_theme_mod( 'understrap_container_type' );
?>

<div class="wrapper" id="hero-template-wrapper">
    <div class="<?php echo esc_attr( $container ); ?>" id="content">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12 content-area" id="primary">
                <main class="site-main" id="main" role="main">
                <?php
                    $bg = get_field('hero_background');
                    if(strlen($bg) > 0) {
                        echo "<section class='hero-section' style='background-image: url($bg);'>";
                    } else {
                        echo "<section class='hero-section'>";
                    }
                    ?>
                    <div class="container-box">
            <span><?php the_field('hero_label') ?></span>
            <h1><?php the_field('hero_title') ?></h1>
                    </div>
          </section>
                    <div class="subnav-container">
                                <?php global $post;
                                $menu_name = get_post_meta($post->ID, "subnav_choice", true);
    
                                $options = array(
                                    'menu' => $menu_name,
                                    'menu_class' => 'subnav',
                                    'echo' => false,
                                );

                                echo wp_nav_menu($options); ?>
                    </div>
                    <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

                        <?php get_template_part( 'loop-templates/content', 'page' ); ?>

                        <?php
                        // If comments are open or we have at least one comment, load up the comment template.
                        if ( comments_open() || get_comments_number() ) :
                            comments_template();
                        endif;
                        ?>

                    <?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>

                </main>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

This is working fine on local WP installation. But in actual Wordpress, whenever I update the template of a page to this and reload the page, it switches back to "Empty page template". I guess this means WP is not saving it,  Please help!

Comment: Two things: In the $options array you are saying echo = false, but right after it you are echoing it out - why not use echo = true and just call the function? Second thing worth mentioning is, that get_template_part fails silently (see official docs), thus giving me to notion that there is something wrong with the inclusion of your template_part. You should look into that in my opinion.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. With echo=true, the menu shoots at the top of the page which is not I want, that is why I've done it that way. I'll look into get_template_part().